# How to bind property with correction?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have custom control(there is no MVVM), code behind:

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Position", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(0, PositionChanged, CorrectPosition));

    private static void PositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static object CorrectPosition(DependencyObject d, object obj)
    {
        var val = (int) obj;
        // max value is 5
        if (val > 5)
            return 5;

        return obj;
    }
}

}
```

Also I have ViewModel (MVVM):

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int _position;
    public int Position
    {
        get { return this._position; }
        set
        {                
            this._position = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Position);
        }

    }
}
```

XAML (MVVM):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow">    
    <CustomControl Position="{Binding Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Window>
```

When I set 6 to Position property of ViewModel it will be 6. 
But value of property Position of CustomControl will be 5.

I want to have the same corrected value for my custom control and viewmodel. And this value will be 5 for this case. I don't want any code duplications.

I need good idea how to synchronize Position correction?

Comment: Imagine this in view model's code: `myVm.Position = 6; Debug.Assert(myVm.Position == 6)`. Are you sure you want this? Consider validation instead.

Comment: It`s not wery good solution for me. Because I need synchronization of Correction (CorrectPosition), it meanss that [ViewModel].Position and [CustomControl].Position will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? XAML:

```
     <CustomControl name="CustomControlPosition" Position="{Binding Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

C#:

```
     private static void PositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         this.Position = CustomControlPosition.Position;
     }
```

Comment: Where will be placed this code:
 this.Position = CustomControlPosition.Position;? 
ViewModel? I using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

When you register your custom property you need to set its metadata so that the value uses two-way binding by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
    PositionChanged, CorrectPosition));
```

Note the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions` enum value.

If this change on its own doesn't solve your problem, then you may have to move the code that's currently in your coerce value callback into your property change callback instead, and get rid of the coerce value callback:

```
private static void PositionChanged(DependencyObject d, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var val = (int) e.NewValue;
    // max value is 5
    if (val > 5)
        ((CustomControl) d).Position = 5;
}
```